# How to use feComponentTransfer inside a mask?

Tags: svg

I am trying to use an SVG to mask an HTML element.

My SVG contains an `feTurbulence` filter that then uses `feComponentTransfer` to bring it down to hard black.

The SVG now looks like I want, but when I try to use it as a mask, it shows nothing.

If I remove the `feFuncR` `feFuncG` `feFuncB` I see the mask is working, it is just having unexpected results. How can I fix this so the mask is using the final output of the SVG?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 150 150">
<mask id="mask">
    <filter id="filter" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
        <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.1" seed="5" />
        <feComponentTransfer>
            <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="0 0 0 1 1 1"/>
            <feFuncR type="discrete" tableValues="0"/>
            <feFuncG type="discrete" tableValues="0"/>
            <feFuncB type="discrete" tableValues="0"/>
        </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" filter="url(#filter)" fill="none" />
  </mask>
</svg>
<div style="width:150px; height:150px; background:blue; mask:url(#mask);"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a filter on mask contents doesn't seem to be supported. The good news is that filters can do masking (feComposite/in) - so just do it all in a filter.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 150 150">
    <filter id="mefilter" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
        <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.1" seed="5" />
        <feComponentTransfer>
            <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="0 0 0 1 1 1"/>
            <feFuncR type="discrete" tableValues="0"/>
            <feFuncG type="discrete" tableValues="0"/>
            <feFuncB type="discrete" tableValues="0"/>
        </feComponentTransfer>
        <feComposite operator="in" in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
</svg>
<div style="width:150px; height:150px; background:blue; filter: url(#mefilter);"></div>
```